# jQuery toggle not staying open

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, click, jquery-animate

trying to toggle a div to expand and contract, it is basically a menu, with subnav. so i initially set height to 48px to hide subnav and in case there is no JS it will still look decent, I then assign a toggle to open and close the div (in this case set the height)

it keeps refreshing and automatically opening the div though. doesn't want to stay open, just expands, gives alert, then closes again.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
$('#nav-wrapper').css('height','48px');
  $('#menu-item-18').click(function() {
    var open = false;
    if(isOpen) {
      $('#nav-wrapper').animate({ height: '-=44' }, 0, function() {}); 
      var isOpen = false;
      alert ('not open')
    } else { 
      $('#nav-wrapper').animate({ height: '+=44' }, 0, function() {}); 
      isOpen = !isOpen; 
      alert ('open') 
    };
  });
});
```

might be way overcomplicating this. I'm sure there is a simpler solution too.

Comment: `isOpen` is not defined here... so it will always return false in your if statement

Comment: Could we see your HTML for this? Thanks!

Comment: oh crap, I had open instead of isOpen.... silly me.

Comment: main problem is that it keeps closing after it opens. so it matches ok, then closes back up. is it reading the height again or something? I am a bit confused. its local so I can't send link but here is a gist of the html it outputs: https://gist.github.com/2423733

Comment: set an alert at the beginning of the function and see if the function is firing twice

Comment: oooo, yeah it's running the .css function again? weird. no idea why. shouldn't it only fire once, and onload? I added the rest of the code so you can see it in context

Comment: ok it seems to be refreshing the page for some reason, this seems to be the problem. no idea why it's refreshing though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isOpen` is defined in local scope and so the value will be always false. You need to move it outside click handler and then you just need `isOpen = !isOpen;` to toggle value. see below,

```
  $('#nav-wrapper').css('height','48px');
  var isOpen = false;

  $('#menu-item-18').click(function() {
    isOpen = !isOpen; 
    if(isOpen) {
      $('#nav-wrapper').animate({ height: '-=44' }, 0, function() {}); 
      alert ('not open')
    } else { 
      $('#nav-wrapper').animate({ height: '+=44' }, 0, function() {}); 
      alert ('open') 
    };
  });
```

Comment: that keeps returning "not open" and still refreshes back to original state like my other script :(

Comment: @Lukasz Ideally it shouldn't. Where do you have this code? Can you setup a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of this?

Comment: I'm idiot, this totally works, I forgot to replace link with "#" it was actually refreshing the page. ug. only thing i had to change was  if(!isOpen) so it would do it in the correct direction. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should work (*and handle multiple elements as well*)

```
$('#menu-item-18').click(function() {
    var isOpen = $(this).is('.open');
    if(isOpen) {
        $('#nav-wrapper').animate({ height: '-=44' }, 0); 
        $(this).removeClass('open');
        alert ('not open');
    } else { 
        $('#nav-wrapper').animate({ height: '+=44' }, 0); 
        $(this).addClass('open');
        alert ('open') ;
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice and easy

```
$('#menu-item-18').click(function() {
    $('#nav-wrapper').slideToggle(200, //speed in ms
      function() {
        //callback (runs after shown or hidden)
        $(this).is(':visible'); //Returns true if not hidden false if hidden
      }
    );     
});
```

Comment: Oh snap... is slideToggle jQuery UI only?

Comment: wish I could do that, I am using wordpress and it has ULs with nested ULs for subnav and the background expands across both but is set on a container div  :/

Comment: nope not jQuery only, UI has more easing options though http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/